# Why doesn't the given command mask other lines?

Tags: command-line, grep, find, pipe, tail

Command: `sudo find / -name miniedit.py -print | grep -i "miniedit" | tail -1`
Output:

```sh
find: ‘/proc/10031/task/10031/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/10031/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
/usr/share/doc/mininet/examples/miniedit.py
```

Expected output: `/usr/share/doc/mininet/examples/miniedit.py`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. You're simply mis-interpreting what you see on screen.

These "extra" lines are error messages indicating directories that `find` couldn't read.
They are written to **standard error** stream, while the expected output (`/usr/share/doc/mininet/examples/miniedit.py`) is written to **standard output** stream.

If you want to get only standard output without standard error, suppress the latter by redirecting it to `/dev/null`, ie.

```
sudo find / -name miniedit.py -print 2>/dev/null | grep -i "miniedit" | tail -1
```

Comment: Ill let you have it ;)

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah, I don't know why I put them there :). Thanks for the correction.